# React Native WebVIew in Android shows a blank page

Tags: webview, react-native, react-native-web

I tried to load a HTML page from my local path in Android using React Native's WebView, as follows.

`var WebViewAndroid = require('react-native-webview-android');`

But I am getting a blank page

```
 <WebViewAndroid
      ref="webViewAndroidSample"
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
      geolocationEnabled={false}
      builtInZoomControls={false}
      url={webapp}
      style={styles.containerWebView}
       />
```

my local path is /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/'myappid'/files/abcd/index.html

Comment: you have `'` in your path. `/'myappid'/`

Comment: no for eg: i gave it as 'myappid' but in my path is /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myappid/files/abcd/index.html